# What is the "Physically Consistent" proper subset of arithmetic?

Tags: lo.logic, physics

Suppose 1st-order arithmetic is inconsistent along with Voevodsky http://video.ias.edu/voevodsky-80th.

It nevertheless remains true that when you have 2 apples and 2 apples, you have 4 apples. Preforming an experiment gives you the result of an experiment, which cannot be inconsistent. So there is a subset of arithmetic that is "necessarily" consistent, given the notion (maps) that arithmetic models reality. The question is, what is this "physically consistent" proper subset of arithmetic?

The second question is, what happens if the physical theory is quantum field theory, where quanta loose their individual identity or "primitive thisness"?

Comment: You don't need to go all the way to quantum field theory for _apples_ to lose their individual identity: all you have to do is tweak the temperature or pressure of your surroundings... 

Comment: I think terms like """primitive thisness""" deserve more than just one set of quotation marks. 

Comment: Even if one takes as an assumption that reality can't be inconsistent, there's no way of knowing that our mental mapping of symbols on a page to reality is "preserving" this consistency. Let me put it this way: why do you feel that the matter of two apples and another two apples making four apples actually has anything to do with the consistency, truth, etc. of the symbol string "2+2=4" in some mathematical system?

Comment: Right. You talk about the consistency of an experiment but your example posits the consistency of a _class_ of experiments. 

Comment: There are lots of problems with the statement 2 apples plus two apples make 4 apples, starting with the impossibility of the definition of an apple, and the same for any "real" object no matter how specific its description can be. Socrates was never able to do maths because of this kind of metaphysical doubts.

Comment: How come this question is not closed after one hour? Where is the Moral Police today?

Comment: Mark: International Rescue have been busy placating students and writing homework solutions for them. (Some of us, anyway)

Comment: Also, labelling this as "qa.quantum-algebra" is incorrect

Comment: This question has a meta thread - http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/987/what-is-the-physically-consistent-proper-subset-of-arithmetic/

Comment: Godelian: Do you have sources to support your claims about Socrates?

Comment: @ François: There is a short but revealing section about Socrates in Carl B. Boyer "A history of mathematics". It is mentioned that in Plato's Fedon there is a dialogue (part of which is quoted) where one can see what profound metaphysical doubts were an obstacle to Socrates interest in maths and natural science. Boyer then infers that the influence of Socrates in the development of maths was meaningless if not even negative, but points that this makes even more surprising the fact that his disciple Plato inspired the maths of IVth century B.C.

Comment: Why does being quantum mean losing arithmetic? If you add two (-1) units of charge to two (-1) units of charge, you get four (-1) units of charge, even if the units of charge are carried by electrons, which have no individual identities.

Comment: @Peter - not really. One could have 5 (-1) units of charge and 1 (+1) unit of charge, or 4+n (-1)s and n (+1)s. I can't quite recall if charge conservation is violated due to uncertainty principles, but I don't think so.

Comment: @David: I believe Peter's point is that even if particles do not have individual identities, your quantum theory can have conserved quantities (such as electrical charge) that obey the usual laws of arithmetic.  For example, one can measure the charge contained in a region by integrating flux through the boundary, and a disjoint union of regions will contain the sum of charges.  This is independent of whether the notion of charge-carrying particle is even well-defined, or whether charge is even quantized.

Answer (score 7):

Presburger arithmetic which is the first order theory of natural numbers with addition has been proven to be consistent by Mojżesz Presburger. My reference for this is the [wikipedia article on Presburger arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic).

Comment: @Gil The wikipedia page you link to mentions doubly-exponential worst-case lower bounds for decidability algorithms for Presburger arithmetic. It would be interesting to know the average-case bounds...

Comment: @David: What does average-case mean here? You need a probability distribution on sentences in arithmetic. How do you get one?

Comment: @Peter Perhaps use Kolmogorov complexity or similar, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2067 - or posts at John Baez's blog Azimuth on algorithmic thermodynamics (http://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/category/information-and-entropy/)